# Embed another xaml silverlight object in page

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, xap

I am totally to Silverlight and am Getting started. I finished the first of the Getting started series [here](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-silverlight-%28hello-world%29) and now seeing into HTML Bridge now over [here](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/overview/working-with-javascript/html-bridge-%28silverlight-quickstart%29). Visual Studio created a website for me when it created the new silverlight application. For the HTML bridge tutorial I created another `silverlight page`(Is this what i should create) and put some code into it.

#### Question

How do I embed this into a html page? ( I know how to do it using markup as well as javascript, I am confused as to how to get the application out of single xap file inside **`ClientBin`** directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Silverlight you are dealing with a single plugin within a HTML page. That plugin is the single XAP file that the HTML page downloads.

Your Silverlight app may also have many pages, but its navigation is not the same as HTML navigation (it uses bookmark URLs to fool the browser into staying on the same page while it changes content). There is only the one HTML page involved.

Initially, just to test your new page, you can change the app.xaml.cs file to create your new Silverlight Page instead of `RootVisual = new Main()` etc. *Long term you need one Silverlight application per separate plugin your require.*

### Update (from comments):

Pages in Silverlight are changed by substituting a visual element of the single main page with the contents of another Silverlight page.

You cannot simply replace the RootVisual (as that can only be set at startup).

Start with a new Navigation or Business application project to see the basics (navigation adds a lot of complexity, but once you see how it works it is pretty cool).

Comment: this code `RootVisual = new ChapterTwo()` helped me but you totally lost in driving me in right direction , if i could navigate from url could you add how to do it with your answer so that i can mark it solved

Comment: @Deeptechtons: I need to know more about what you are trying to accomplish in order to give more relevant examples. Can you clarify?

Comment: i am trying to add more than one page in single silverlight application, i want to browse through all the pages in that application by embedding it in a aspx, html file that's all there is i want

Comment: Updated. Start with the Business App sample you can create in VS 2010.